# Will checking the last Modified Date of a WIN7 TaskScheduler file (StartRecording), by means of a batch file, automatically update it?

Tags: windows-7, batch, windows-task-scheduler

I'm aiming for a quick way to monitor the last Modified Date of a WIN7 TaskScheduler file for Windows Media Center - probably quicker by a batch file than by clicking down 7 levels in Win Explorer.

The 4KB TaskScheduler file of concern is:

C:\Windows\System32\Tasks\Microsoft\Windows\Media Center\StartRecording

Before I start trying to code this as a .bat file, can anyone advise me whether checking the Modified Date of a taskscheduler file (unlike typical application files) will itself modify the file date, so I won't be able to see what the file date was immediately prior to the coded check.

I'm not an expert and don't want to waste time on a potentially fruitless task.

Thank you.

Comment: Have you tried creating a dummy file, checking its last modified date, modifying the file, checking it again, waiting 5 minutes, and checking a third time?

Comment: @MichaelHarvey I think it would have to be a similar type of TaskScheduler file. I'll try that. Thanks.

Comment: Why do you think reading a file last-modified date would change that date?

Comment: @MichaelHarvey TaskScheduler files for Windows Media Canter get updated many timea a day, and I suspect they change when I check them - which is the reason for the question. I do know that this doesn't happen for most file types, Thanks for sticking with it.